# Return records that match 2 items of a list in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: `links` and `links_keywords`. `links` has an `id` column and `links_keywords` has a `link_id` column and a `keyword_id` column. Given a `links.id`, I want to get all `links.id`s that have at least 2 matching keywords as the given `links.id`.

For example, to get the `links.id`s with only 1 matching keyword, I can do something like this:

```
SELECT links.id 
FROM links 
INNER JOIN keywords ON keywords.link_id=links.id 
LEFT JOIN links links2 on links2.id=keywords.link_id 
WHERE links2.id=1
```

Comment: What is the full table structure? show the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `column` has one value which can match either of 5 values on the right... What is the second value?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking one thing and typing another. I'll fix the question right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join the two tables, group by the id and apply the "at least 2 matching" condition:

```
SELECT links.id
FROM links
JOIN keywords ON keywords.link_id = links.id
GROUP BY links.id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Or, if you're already using foreign key constraints:

```
SELECT link_id AS id
FROM keywords
GROUP BY link_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: +1 . . . but you don't need the join at all.  Just do everything with `keywords.link_id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Indeed :) I've added that alternative to the answer, thanks!